# play mp3 in flash from byteArray - need to be able to seek on mp3

Tags: flash, mp3, arrays

I am going to have a byte array of an mp3.  I do not want to save the file locally to the clients machine, rather I want to play the mp3 from the byte array (if possible), or some sort of memory stream if that would be a feasible option (convert the byte array to a stream then play).

My only caveat is that I'll need to be able to seek on the mp3 to different points of the audio track and I'm not sure that I can do that with the mp3 contained in a byte array.

please advise.

Any code you can provide to support your answer would be greatly appreciated.

TIA for your valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

There is a library for encoding MP3.
https://github.com/kikko/Shine-MP3-Encoder-on-AS3-Alchemy

For the caveat, use the `SoundChannel.position` to know where mark the notations.

Comment: the shine library is for encoding wav sounds to mp3 as best I can tell.  I'm downloading the mp3 into a bytearray and need to convert it back to an mp3.  Is this possible?

Comment: Sure, in this case I think you just need to use Sound.loadCompressedDataFromByteArray().

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html#loadCompressedDataFromByteArray()